# How do I sync files from an EC2 instance to a local Macbook using rsync?

Tags: amazon-ec2, rsync

I'm trying to sync files from an EC2 instance to my local Macbook. I have a `config` file on my Macbook within the `~/.ssh` folder where my EC2 configuration is stored under `Host exprod`. The following commands are being run from my Macbook.

I tried the following command to sync the files.

`sudo rsync -av exprod:~/production /Users/username/Downloads/`

However, that did not work and I see the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname exprod: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/aaefcfd1-5c95-11ed-8734-2e32217d8374/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/io.c(453) [receiver=2.6.9]
```

I then used this command:

`sudo rsync -av -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/myawskey.pem" ~/production/* /Users/myusername/Downloads/`

```
building file list ...
rsync: link_stat "/Users/myusername/production" failed: No such file or directory (2)
0 files to consider

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/aaefcfd1-5c95-11ed-8734-2e32217d8374/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The first error suggests that `exprod` is not picked up. Perhaps because you used `sudo` which causes the command to run as root (and look in a different location for the ssh config), or maybe the ssh config is broken. Try without sudo and if you get the same error, share your ssh config file.

Comment: Removing `sudo` worked. Thanks.